# Run Batch file as Other user/Build User from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, authorize

How can i call a Windows batch file to run as build user other than the OS User that Jenkins run as. For my situation, Batch has authorization to build user but not the OS user.

I tried to use [CPAU](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/) supplying user id and password and it works manually when executing the command through CMD window, but not from Jenkins as Jenkins is instantly killing the second window that CPAU opens to run the Batch.

I tried using [Authorize Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authorize+Project+plugin) and set the Authorization to run as build user. But its failing as batch is still run as OS User, not the build user.

I read some suggestions to use Slave node and run Batch file on Slave node, However I didn't get much help online on how to do so.

Please provide any suggestions to get this issue sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one jenkins slave and launch the slave using build user.
To learn how to create slave Here's [a link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines)

Login to machine as build user and launch the slave. In case of java security issue, go to Configure java(java control panel) and add website in security tab.

Now in job confguration Set the "Restrict where this job can be run" check box and specify the name of your slave.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. I followed the link and installed Slave agent. However since its offline. I installed it as Windows Service and changed "Log On" to Build user and it worked.